# How to set the third party python package on ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed googlemaps, numpy and polyline using pip install command on ubuntu 16.04. As I run the code using sudo python code.py, it works. But, When I use rospy in code and run it as rosrun package code.py the code doesn't work. It shows problem in connecting googlemap API. I want to include these python packages(googlemaps..) on ROS so that the code works on ROS. How to  do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264403/how-to-set-the-third-party-python-package-on-ros?/) by [amar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30853/amar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-21**:
Why do you run it with sudo? Do you get errors running code.py without sudo?

**Comment by [amar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30853/amar/) on 2017-06-22**:
to run a pyhton script i use sudo. Without sudo i get errors as ros can't find the pyhton packages which i installed using pip. I just want to know how to use googlemaps , numpy and polyline on ROS. I want to know how to run the code with these modules using rosrun.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Using `sudo` is almost never necessary, and should certainly not be required for starting regular Python scripts that load a few libraries. Did you use a virtualenv to install your libraries? Can you tell us the output of:

```
$ python
...
>>> import numpy <enter>
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
And perhaps also: `which python`?

**Comment by [amar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30853/amar/) on 2017-06-22**:
python- 2.7.12 . I installed those packages using pip install command. I want to run the python script using rosrun so that i can publish data. But when i use rosrun the code doesn't work. using sudo to run the code is not a concern

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:\

> using sudo to run the code is not a concern

it *is* a concern, as it should not be necessary and seems to point to 'larger' problems with your setup / configuration.

`pip`-installed modules should be usable under any account. And should also work 'with ROS'.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Can you tell us what the output is of `echo $PYTHONPATH`? Both *before* and *after* you have `source`d `setup.bash`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Also: please edit your original question and include the errors that you encounter when trying to run your node using `rosrun`. Use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to format everything properly.

**Comment by [amar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30853/amar/) on 2017-06-22**:
echo $PYTHONPATH results /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks!! I solved the problem. I tried again by creating a catkin workspace and it works using rosrun.

---

Originally posted by [amar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30853/amar/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
So it was a configuration error.

Good to hear that you resolved it.